# How to correctly get a value from goroutines?

Tags: go

I have the following algorithm:

- make GET request to API;
- get all events id;
- make uri using events id and make another **GET** request;
- parse response and return value

So, I decided to use goroutines. The first goroutine is making **GET** request, getting `response.Body(JSON)`, parsing it and sending it to another goroutine, which also makes **GET** request, processes data and returns it.

```
func main() {
    client := tools.HttpClient()
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)

    wg.Add(1)

    chnl := make(chan string)
    chnlr := make(chan string)
    scann := &scanner{}

    var fullLine string
    go scann.getSports(chnl, client, wg)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        go scann.getOdds(chnl, chnlr, client, wg)
        fullLine = <-chnlr
    }
    fmt.Println(fullLine)
    wg.Wait()
}

type scanner struct{}

// Getting live id events and send it to other func-goroutine.
// It sends only data to channel [>> chan<- string].
func (*scanner) getSports(chnl chan<- string, client *http.Client, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // make request
    body := tools.GetRequest(client, "GET", API["sports"])
    // parse json
    var s Sport
    json.Unmarshal(body, &s)

    var count int16
    for _, rawdata := range s {
        // get only necessary events id
        for _, sport := range rawdata.Payload.CompetitionsWithEvents {
            // if sport id not in map
            for key := range SportsMap {
                if sport.Competition.SportID != key {
                    continue
                }
                // send event id to  goroutine with chanal
                // this goroutine will make request to get markets
                for _, event := range sport.Events {
                    chnl <- event.ID
                    count++
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("[Total events] -", count)
}

// Geting live events markets.
func (*scanner) getOdds(chnl <-chan string, chnlr chan<- string, client *http.Client, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    // var fullLine []interface{}
    for {
        // make uri
        uri := fmt.Sprintf(API["odds"] + <-chnl + ":")
        // make request
        body := tools.GetRequest(client, "GET", uri)
        converted := MakeMeta(body)

        result, err := json.MarshalIndent(converted, "", " ")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        chnlr <- string(result)
    }
}
```

Its working good, but only if I wont return any value from `scanner.getOdds()`

```
 func main() {
        client := tools.HttpClient()
        wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    
        wg.Add(1)
    
        chnl := make(chan string)
        scann := &scanner{}
    
        go scann.getSports(chnl, client, wg)
        for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
            go scann.getOdds(chnl,client, wg)
        }
        wg.Wait()
    }
```

**P.S.** I`m trying not to use Semaphores.

Comment: Correct. If you want to get a result from a goroutine it should be sent over a channel.

Comment: @Adrian Cool, so what the plan?

Comment: Have you looked at any easily found concurrency examples? [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/2), [Worker Pools](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools), [Pipelines and Cancellation](https://go.dev/blog/pipelines), etc... (I don't know why you mention semaphores here, but maybe the worker pool example is what you're looking for?)

Comment: @JimB Nope, from Python to Golang just like a rocket!)

Comment: @JimB Maybe I will try to use Worker Pools, oh my...)